# why at every function call the value keeps on updating?

Tags: python, function, class, oop, pickle

This function of mine keeps on updating value of (q3) to its last value at every function call.This is a method of a class.First time calling the value is accurate and right but at time time of further calling the same function the value gets updated automatically.I want the function to update its value when i tell it to do so as it is dependent on another method to update its value but it updates itself on every call.please help me with this.yes ai am asking about qa3. Thank You

```
def disp(self):
        k2=[]
        tgc=open("filename.txt","rb+")
        fl=open("filename2.txt","rb+")
        try:
            while True:
                self.f2=pickle.load(tgc)
                self.fg=pickle.load(fl)
                k2.append(self.f2)
                kg.append(self.fg)
        except EOFError:
            qa3=0
            for i in kg:
                if "L"in i:
                    qa2=i[:-1]
                    qa3=qa3+int(qa2)
                else:
                    qa3=qa3+int(i[0])
            print (qa3)
            tgc.close()
            fl.close()
```

Comment: Did you mean to ask about `qa3`?

Comment: yes sir i was asking about qa3 only

Comment: First thing to note is that ‘qa3’ is initialised to 0 and accumulates values from ‘kg’. Then it is printed out. Next thing to note is that ‘qa3’ is local to this method and cannot be accessed from the outside. So once ‘qa3’ is calculated it is printed out and thrown away.

Comment: qa3 just has to print the values the above codes give to it. the problem is that whenever this function gets the whole thing works and qa3 updates itself thus giving false value. iwant it to update its value whn i tell it to do.this function should not update its value depending upon the number of times i am calling a function.

Comment: In the world of programming `whenever this function get called` and `when I tell it to` are exactly the same thing. How should this method know that you don't want `qa3` to be calculated when it is called?

Comment: So what should I do so that the value of qa3 does does not gets automatically updated?

Comment: You could have two versions of the method. One for each circumstance. The caller then gets to decide whether `qa3` should be updated or not by calling one and not the other.

Comment: can you help me out in what way to do that.can u provide some changes in my code to help me out.

Comment: can I use infinite loop for dealing with a problem like  this. like using an infinite loop with a variable such the part of function works on the basis of a variable ?